# How can I tell what chrome features are released?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I was excited to find the documentation of the url_handlers manifest attribute here: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/url_handlers.html

I learned about it by reading various threads on the chrome developer forums, and some SO questions related to it. So then I tried it, and I got an error saying that it was only available in the Dev channel, not the stable channel. (I then downloaded the dev channel version, and it works just as documented.)

Does google document someplace which APIs are actually released, and which ones are just teasing us poor developers?

Is there some way for me to track an API feature, so I can start using it as soon as it is released to the stable channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API Index](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index.html) page has Chrome release numbers next to each API family. For manifest features, it's not as user-friendly. You must visit [the corresponding configuration file](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/_manifest_features.json&l=398) in the source code and see the availability of a given manifest key. In this case, as you can see, url_handlers is dev-channel-only at this time.